# R find the word that starts with "A" and has fixed length

Tags: r

I want to find the word that starts with A and has 6 numbers after the A. See below, I want the first `A123456` to return TRUE, and the second `Approval` to return FALSE. Because the pattern I'm looking for is a word starts with Capital A with 6 numbers after it.

```
grepl("\\<A", c("A123456","Approval"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear if you want TRUE also for something that has more than just 6 numbers after A e.g. "A123456zz". If so, remove the $ at the end of the regex

```
grepl("^A[0-9]{6}$", c("A123456","Approval"))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

https://regex101.com/r/BiYlhK/1

I may as well copy/paste the explanation of this regex given by regex101, because it does a better job describing the patterns than I could

**^**

asserts position at start of a line

**A**

matches the character A with index 6510 (4116 or 1018) literally (case sensitive)

**[0-9]**

Matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)

**{6}**

matches the previous token exactly 6 times

**$**

asserts position at the end of a line

Comment: This is perfect! Can you point to me where to find the documentation that explains what each symbols do? This works, but I want to learn how to use each symbol as the scenario will likely change for future use

Comment: This site will explain regex you type on the right hand side: https://regex101.com/r/BiYlhK/1

Answer (score 3):

Quantifiers are meant for this type of work. '\\d' finds any digit (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) while the '{'--the quantifier--allows you to specify how many matches you want with range: `{LOWER_BOUND, UPPER_BOUND}`. Excluding the comma means you want an exact number of matches. The stringr implementation is provided below.

```
stringr::str_detect(c("A123456", "Approval"), "A\\d{6}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `grepl` like below

```
> grepl("^A\\d{6}", c("A123456", "Approval"))
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```